# specified GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that looks like:

```
id   b_id   picture
---+------+----------------------
1  |   1  |     head.jpg
2  |   1  |     willson.jpg
3  |   1  |     babolat.jpg
4  |   2  |     head.jpg
5  |   2  |     prince.jpg
6  |   3  |     yonex.jpg
7  |   4  |     fila.jpg
8  |   2  |     brooks.jpg
9  |   0  |     sergio_tacchini.jpg
10 |   0  |     nike.jpg
11 |   0  |     lacoste.jpg
12 |   0  |     dunlop.jpg
```

Now I want to `GROUP BY` b_id but ONLY if b_id is not 0.

**Output has to be like this:**

```
id   b_id    picture
---+------+------------------------
1  | 1    |   head.jpg
4  | 2    |   head.jpg
6  | 3    |   yonex.jpg
7  | 4    |   fila.jpg
9  | 0    |   sergio_tacchini.jpg
10 | 0    |   nike.jpg
11 | 0    |   lacoste.jpg
12 | 0    |   dunlop.jpg
```

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Edit should looks like:

`
id  b_id    picture
1   1       head.jpg
4   2       head.jpg
6   3       yonex.jpg
7   4       fila.jpg
9   0       sergio_tacchini.jpg
10  0       nike.jpg
11  0       lacoste.jpg
12  0       dunlop.jpg
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining Ullas and John Woo's:

```
   SELECT a.id, 
          a.b_id, 
          a.picture
     FROM table_name a
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT b_id, MIN(id) min_id
         FROM table_name
        WHERE b_id > 0
     GROUP BY b_id
          ) b 
       ON a.b_id = b.b_id
      AND a.id = b.min_id
    WHERE a.b_id = 0
       OR b.b_id IS NOT NULL
```

[See Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22f960/7)

Comment: @Alek_86 Thank you.. I included the other answer in my fiddle to show where it breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**QUERY**

```
 (SELECT MIN(id) AS 'id',b_id,picture
 FROM table_name WHERE b_id >0
 GROUP BY b_id)
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT id,b_id,picture
 FROM table_name WHERE b_id=0);
```

**[FIND SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9026a/3)**

Comment: Thanks for answer but this doesn't work for me. With this sql i getting grouped all rows, but i need to group only rows that b_id is not zero (0).

Comment: This is not correct, picture is not guaranteed to match up to the id.
Change the id of row 4 to 13 in the fiddle and see.

Comment: @Arth: Sir, Please check the fiddle. got the output as OP asked.

Comment: @Ullas Check my last comment.. I have just run it like that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Arth picture is just example. I tested sql and it's working for me.

Comment: @Alek_86 It may be an example, but GROUP BY doesn't work like this, if it's wrong in a simple example then it'll be wrong in your code. I'll add a better answer.

Comment: @Alek_86 see my answer and fiddle.

Comment: @Arth i'm commented your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery gets the smallest `ID` per `b_ID`. In order to get the other columns (*in this case, only one column*), the result of the subquery is then joined to the table itself provided that it match the `b_id` and the minimum valud of `ID`.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.b_id, a.picture
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  b_id, MIN(a.id) min_id
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY b_id
        ) b ON a.b_id = b.b_id
                AND a.ID = b.min_id
```